# Randomly select 10% of elements with '0' value and replace them with np.nan in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am still fairly new to pandas/numpy and I though this would be an easy thing to find but I couldn't.

I want to randomly select 10% of the zero values in my df and change them to np.nan, and then return the dataset to use

Thís is to simulate missing value of my negative cases, as my df consists of binary variables, so I am only interested in augmenting 10% of the zeros.

I hope this makes sense!

```
index_nan = np.random.choice(df.size, 10, replace=False)
 
data.ravel()[index_nan] = np.nan
print(df)
```

I want to do this but (10 is 10% of my data) but I don't know how to only effect the '0' values in my df

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You don't simply "find" it; you build it from the individual steps you already know.  That's what programming is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your questions, you display the rows in a dataframe that are equal to a particular value using the following:

```py
df.loc[df['column']==VALUE]
```

You can count how many rows are equal to a value with:

```py
(df['column']==VALUE).sum()
```

If you use the index of the dataframe as the population, then use the built-in random module to sample the index

```py
indices_to_change = random.sample(
    (df['column']==VALUE).index, 
    (df['column']==VALUE).sum() / 10)

df.loc[indices_to_change, 'column'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Ah thank you, but that will only work for a series ? or a column? I want to do it for the whole dataset. I tried it but it did not allow me to choose multiple columns. Again sorry I am new to pandas/numpy !

Comment: When you say 10% of "your data", do you mean 10% of the rows that have a 0 occurring in one or more columns? Or do you intend 10% of the total 0-entries? Also, does your DataFrame represent observations (rows) and variables (columns)?

Comment: @arnoldhenry, I can update my answer once I hear back from you.